# reducing space between punctuation in xeCJK

Tags: xecjk

I try to reduce the space between the dot and the apostrophy in `xeCJK`:

[image]

There is a detailed manual but I cannot read it. Is the manual available in English somewhere and if not, could you please help and say which of the commands are doing what I want.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xeCJK}


\begin{document}

`Chris，我们认为David看见了。'

\end{document}
```

Comment: For single use you could try `\!` before the apostrophe.

Comment: No, the manual has lots of stuff: LongPunct, PunctWidth and so on. But I do not want to do lunatic stuff that has side effects I do not understand.

Comment: OK. Google translator actually produces usable output. So I can understand the manual now. `\xeCJKsetup{PunctStyle=...}` seems to do the job.